# Как отследить начало загрузки файла со стороны клиента на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events

ситуация такая: есть сайт с формой, форма подкрепляет файл и отправляет на сервер, по кнопке "отправить" кнопка становится неактивной и включается секундомер (показывает, что процесс обработки файла идет), после обработки файла сервер отправляет обработанный файл обратно к клиенту и вот этот процесс нужно отследить, чтобы остановить секундомер и сделать кнопку снова активной. Как это можно сделать на JavaScript на стороне клиента? 
Заказчик не хочет на стороне сервера что-то добавлять.

Comment: А можно ваш код глянуть? _отправляет обработанный файл обратно к клиенту_ это в каком формате он его отправляет? Ссылкой? В любом случае, скорее всего достаточно дождаться `success` выполнения запроса

Comment: У меня имеется только клиентская сторона, на которой просто форма (<form action="/run" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w3-container w3-card-4">)  с полем для выбора файла в формате *.xlsx и кнопкой "Отправить", а на выходе он автоматически загружает обработанный файл в формате *-result.xlsx, страница не перезагружается, не перенаправляется, ссылка не появляется, просто автоматическая загрузка в папку по умолчанию.